# generate uncertainty for a prediction using JAGS via rjags in R

Tags: r, bayesian, jags, uncertainty

Say I have a relationship between two variables, that I have successfully fit using JAGS via the `rjags` package for R. Below is the code to generate the data, and the fitted JAGS model.

data:

```
#generate data
age <- seq(1:200)
age.m1 <- 0.1    * exp(-age * .1) #mortality rate declines initially from juvenile stage
age.m2 <- 0.001 * exp(age* 0.015) #mortality rate creeps up as trees get older
x <- age.m1 + age.m2 #combine the two mortality rates
#generate some scatter in the data to plot
y <- age.m3 + rnorm(length(age.m3),0, 0.002)
```

JAGS model:

```
require(rjags)

jags.model = "
model {
    for (i in 1:N){
        y[i] ~ dnorm(y.hat[i], tau)
        y.hat[i] <- c*exp(-a * x[i]) + d*exp (b * x[i])
        }
    a ~ dnorm(0, .0001)I(0,10)
    b ~ dnorm(0, .0001)I(0,10)
    c ~ dnorm(0, .0001)I(0,10)
    d ~ dnorm(0, .0001)I(0,10)
    tau <- pow(sigma, -2)
    sigma ~ dunif(0, 100)
}
"

data = list(y=y, x=x, N = length(y))

j.model <- jags.model(file = textConnection(jags.model),
                          data=data,
                          n.chains=3)

#sample from the posterior
jags.out   <- coda.samples (model = j.model,
                            variable.names = c('a','b','c','d'),
                            n.iter = 5000)
```

I can then predict `y` as a function of `x`, based on known values of `x`, and parameter estimates from my JAGS model, like this:

```
#grab parameter values, estimate y over the range of x.
pars <- summary(jags.out)$statistics[,1]
m.out <- pars[3] * exp(-pars[1] * x) + pars[4] * exp(pars[2]* x)

#plot predicted y over the range of x
plot(m.out ~ x, pch=16, cex = 0, main = 'fitted JAGS model', ylim=c(0,0.1))
lines(smooth.spline(m.out ~ age), lwd = 2, col = 'purple')
par(new=T)
plot(scatter, pch=16, cex = 0.5, ylim=c(0,0.1))
```

[image: fitted estimates]

However, this is only the estimate of the mean. Using R, how can I go about estimating +/- 1 standard deviation on this mean prediction estimate, accounting for uncertainty in all the parameter values used to generate it? If this was a fit done in lm/glm I would use the `predict` function to generate +/- 1 standard error of the fit.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done by estimating the `tau` parameter, the measurement of the precision of `y`, when calling `coda` while sampling the JAGS model output. Modify the coda line to include `tau`:

```
#sample from the posterior
jags.out   <- coda.samples (model = j.model,
                            variable.names = c('a','b','c','d','tau'),
                            n.iter = 5000)
```

Then estimate the upper and lower bounds of y by addding or substracting `sqrt(1/tau)`, which is the standard deviation of the estimate.

```
pars <- summary(jags.out)$statistics[,1]
m.out       <- pars[3] * exp(-pars[1] * age) + pars[4] * exp(pars[2]* age)
m.out.plus  <- pars[3] * exp(-pars[1] * age) + pars[4] * exp(pars[2]* age) + sqrt(1/pars[5])
m.out.minus <- pars[3] * exp(-pars[1] * age) + pars[4] * exp(pars[2]* age) - sqrt(1/pars[5])
```

You can then plot a shaded confidence interval that represents +/- 1 standard devation with the following code:

```
plot(m.out ~ age, pch=16, cex = 0, main = 'fitted JAGS model', ylim=c(0,0.1))
lines(smooth.spline(m.out ~ age), lwd = 2, col = 'purple')
polygon(c((1:length(x)), rev(1:length(x))),c(m.out.plus, rev(m.out.minus)), col=adjustcolor('purple', 0.3), lty=0)
par(new=T)
plot(scatter, pch=16, cex = 0.5, ylim=c(0,0.1))
```

[image: fitted model with confidence interval]